# Why doesn't Git track files modified in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, git, command-line

I'm using Git on the terminal to commit changes & push them to a remote repo.

Git can recognize when I create a file or modify a file via VS Code. However, when I work on my files on Xcode and save them, Git doesn't track any changes. It tells me:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

What's the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: And the files you edit with Xcode are definitely within the repo, have actual changes and are not ignored?

Comment: In `Xcode`, Go to `Source Control` menu and click on `Fetch and Refresh Status` and tell us what happens next

Comment: I modified the same files in VS Code later and git recognized the changes.

Comment: @staticVoidMan hello i just did that and checked "git status" it says : On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean

Comment: @Biffen hi yes i'm positive its in the same repo because git tracked the changes when i modified the file in VS Code, it only doesn't track it when i change it on Xcode

Comment: @goldfrappp Check `git remote show origin` and reconfirm. The Xcode project might be in a folder that is not under git control or linked to another git url.

Comment: @goldfrapp : can you double check that the path to the file you edit in Xcode really is the path you expect on your disk ?

Comment: @LeGEC i modified "ViewController.swift" inside of Xcode and pressed save but Git couldn't track the change then i went to the source files and opened "ViewController.swift" using VS Code and modified it, then Git recognized that the file changed!

Comment: @staticVoidMan hello i just checked it responded with this "macs-MacBook-Pro:Autolayout-Exercises mac$ git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: https://github.com/gfrapp/Autolayout-Exercises.git
  Push  URL: https://github.com/gfrapp/Autolayout-Exercises.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branch:
    master tracked
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    master merges with remote master
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (up to date)
macs-MacBook-Pro:Autolayout-Exercises mac$"

Comment: when I committed and pushed to the remote repo for the first time all the contents of the files were pushed to the remote repo normally, however whenever i modify any file inside of Xcode Git doesn't recognize the changes

Comment: @goldfrappp are you sure your `Xcode` project is same as the one you open with `Visual Studio`? Analyze this very carefully

Comment: @staticVoidMan Yes its the same project, I just clicked on ViewController.swift from the folder on my Desktop and it didn't contain the modified content that is inside of Xcode, I think there is a problem in the connection between Xcode and the source files on my desktop??

Comment: @goldfrappp Two more things to check. First, go to Xcode's Source Control preferences and make sure the Enable Source Control checkbox is selected. Second, in the Finder press Cmd-Shift-Period to show invisible files. Go to your Xcode project folder and make sure there's a .git folder inside the project folder.